Connecting a Payment Link to a Landing Page for Business Validation
happy to be redirected to potentially a more suitable Stack Exchange Site for the following question, but thought this would be a good place to start. I have a business idea, and would like to carry out some customer validation before launching a website, marketing etc etc. Rather than asking people I know in this space "Are you interested in this, or would you pay for this", I would prefer to collect cold hard facts and offer 3 tiers of customer added value; Tier 1 would be free, Tier 2 would cost a small fee for a one off bespoke offering and Tier 3 would offer updates to the paid offering, as market data changes throughout the year.
I am currently thinking of launching a landing page using something like Mailchimp or Sendfox, where it would just collect a Customer Name and email address. This would generate a Welcome email with a PDF attached containing the free general info I am offering. The email would also then have Google Form links to Tier 2 and Tier 3 offerings if the customer would like more tailored information, and these Google Forms would have a PayPal payment link attached to them for an upfront payment (I see Payable Apps can support this). Just in case it sounds a small bit scammy, I will only be sending this to people who know and trust me - but I am also conscious that these same people would like to support me verbally, so a better measure of their interest would be if they are actually willing to part with their hard earned money for the services I am offering.
Is this a good way to do this? Is attaching PDFs (10 mB) to an auto-generated email easy and affordable (would prefer to stay in the lowest bracket of pricing for now as this is literally just a business validation exercise). Are there other/better ways to do this? For example, embedding the Google Form and Payment links on a landing page? Is it best to only ever have 1 link on a landing page, or could I have links to the 3 tiered offerings? Happy to hear any thoughts on this or other approaches I should research.

Welcome to the site! Unfortunately, your question sounds less like a design question (at least I do not feel qualified as a designer to answer).

I’m voting to close this question because it's not about design, but I know no better stackexchange site.

Why do you want any of your content in an attached PDF? If you're making your users read an email and a landing page it might be easiest for the user (and yourself) to have the tier 1 details in both places.
I understand your user flow as: Email capture landing page - Welcome email - Service sign up landing page. That all seems pretty standard and your users should be familiar with this flow. Only UX recommendations I can think of are ditch the PDF and include the form and payment links all on the same page.
Leaving the UX-side to talk more about customer/market validation. What is your reason for initially only contacting known supporters? Is that b/c of Mailchimp's list validation reqs? A countering concept would be engaging with qualified yet unknown contacts first for validation and refinement, then emailing your known a-list.

Hi Dylan, thank you for the answer. The Tier 1 offering of content will take more of a report format totaling approx. 10 pages. Lots of tables and market analysis for the sector my contacts are in. In time, this will be interactive on a website, and allow them to filter and refine the data as they choose, but for now, I just want to give them a flavor of what that could be, and assess their interest before going to the effort of developing & launching a website like this.

As they are my friends, I am confident they are likely to say things like "sure that's a good idea", and like the free aspect to it, but ultimately, I would like users who to pay for this type of analysis, which is why I would like to test their interest through a small fee for a bespoke report tailored to their needs. If this initial validation exercise is successful, after gathering feedback and refining some more, I will definitely look to further validate with a group of target users who I don't know personally, but have a mutual contact in my network

Because of the report format nature of the Tier 1 offering, I thought a PDF might be good. I guess another option would be for them to input a name and email and the landing would reveal the same report embedded on it? Is this quite doable or what would be your approach here?

Lastly, any thoughts on a package I should try and use to achieve all of this? Thanks!
